# CVXPY Quadratic Programming - ArpackNoConvergence error and AssertionError

Tags: python, error-handling, linear-algebra, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to use the Python package CVXPY to solve a quadratic problem but I keep getting errors. Could you help me?

Here is my code:

```
p = lasso.p # This is a number
Sigma_opt = lasso.Sigma_opt # This is a positive semi-definite matrix of shape (p,p)
rho_pair = lasso.rho_pair # Vector of shape (p,)
mu = lasso.mu # Positive scalar number.

def solve_2nd_problem(p, Sigma_opt, rho_pair, mu):
  beta = cp.Variable(p) # Variable to optimize
  obj = cp.Minimize(0.5 * cp.quad_form(beta, Sigma_opt) - rho_pair.T @ beta + mu * cp.norm1(beta)) # Objective to minimize
  constraints = [] # Constraints

  # Solve the optimization problem
  prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
  prob.solve()

  return beta.value

beta_opt = solve_2nd_problem(p, Sigma_opt, rho_pair, mu)
```

I get `ArpackNoConvergence: ARPACK error -1: No convergence (11281 iterations, 0/1 eigenvectors converged) [ARPACK error -14: ZNAUPD did not find any eigenvalues to sufficient accuracy.]`

After reading what was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117123/cvxpy-quadratic-programming-arpacknoconvergence-error), I tried to change `Sigma_opt` by `cp.psd_wrap(Sigma_opt)` and to set `cp.settings.EIGVAL_TOL = 1e-06`, but doing so I am now getting this error:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-1fbde9ad6b58> in <cell line: 19>()
     17   return beta.value
     18 
---> 19 beta_opt = solve_2nd_problem(p, Sigma_opt, rho_pair, mu)

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cvxpy/reductions/complex2real/complex2real.py in canonicalize_expr(self, expr, real_args, imag_args, real2imag, leaf_map)
    179             return result
    180         else:
--> 181             assert all(v is None for v in imag_args)
    182             real_out = expr.copy(real_args)
    183             return real_out, None

AssertionError:
```

I am not sure if I well understood what was happening here, but I now for a fact that my matrix Sigma_opt is PSD (as `np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(Sigma_opt) > 0)` and `(Sigma_opt.T == Sigma_opt).all()` both return `True`).

The matrix Sigma_opt is of shape (p = 946, p = 946) and rho_pair is of shape (p = 946,).

Do you know how I could fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem caused by a numerical instability in the solver used by CVXPY, it uses the SCS solver, which may have problems with large or ill-conditioned problems, , lets try a different one like MOSEK or ECOS, which might be more reliable.

First install it

```
!pip install mosek
!pip install ecos
```

then we can modify the `solver_2nd_problem` here is the code:

```
def solve_2nd_problem(p, Sigma_opt, rho_pair, mu):
    beta = cp.Variable(p) # Variable to optimize
    obj = cp.Minimize(0.5 * cp.quad_form(beta, Sigma_opt) - rho_pair.T @ beta + mu * cp.norm1(beta)) # Objective to minimize
    constraints = [] # Constraints

    # Solve the optimization problem
    prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
    prob.solve(solver=cp.MOSEK, verbose=True)  # Change this to cp.ECOS if you prefer ECOS solver

    return beta.value
```

Comment: I tried both solvers (MOSEK and ECOS), but the AssertionError remains somehow :(.
Maybe I could share the matrix Sigma_opt and the vector rho_pair (I do not know how to do so)?

Comment: There might be a complex-valued issue in your problem, which is causing the AssertionError, try checking if any of your input data has complex values or very small imaginary parts, use unmpy.real to extract the real part and numpy.imag to extract the imaginary part of your matrices or vectors.

Comment: Ok! My father calls me for dinner, I try right after!

Comment: OMG, it does work!!! Thank you! I spent almost 3 days on this problem :( I am so happy that it now works!

For the record: I replaced Sigma_opt by cp.psd_wrap(np.real(Sigma_opt)), as Sigma_opt presented values like "2.45 + 0.0j" instead of "2.45".

Comment: You welcome :) and congratulation on fixing your problem.